# need to output BitLocker status to txt file

Tags: powershell

I have a simple PowerShell script to check the status of BitLocker drive encryption on a computer on the network. I'd like for the script to determine the status of multiple computers in a text file.

Here's my basic script so far that Nathan Rice had helped with:

```psh
$TextFilePath = Read-Host "What is the path to the text file?"
If (Test-Path $TextFilePath) {
    $ComputersArray = Get-Content $TextFilePath
    ForEach ($Computer in $ComputersArray) {
        If (Test-Connection $Computer -Count 1) {
            $ComputerStatus = manage-bde -status -cn "$Computer"
            Write-Host($ComputerStatus)
        } Else {
            Write-Host("$Computer appears to be offline.")
        }
    }
} Else {
    Write-Error "The text file was not found, check the path."
}
```

I modified the code but it only writes one result to the text file, meaning if I have 5 computers in the list, it writes only the results for the first computer:

```psh
$TextFilePath = Read-Host "What is the path to the text file?"
If (Test-Path $TextFilePath){
    $ComputersArray = Get-Content $TextFilePath
    ForEach ($Computer in $ComputersArray) {
        If (Test-Connection $Computer -Count 1) {
            $ComputerStatus = manage-bde -status -cn "$Computer" |
               Out-File -filepath "c:\users\enduser\Bitlocker-Status.txt"
        } Else {
            Write-Host("$Computer appears to be offline.")
        }
    }
} Else {
    Write-Error "The text file was not found, check the path."
}
```

I'd like it to write the results for each device to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a collection of results.  After the loop, write the collection to a file.

```
$TextFilePath = Read-Host "What is the path to the text file?"
If (Test-Path $TextFilePath){
    $ComputersArray = Get-Content $TextFilePath
    $ComputerStatusCol = @()
ForEach ($Computer in $ComputersArray) {
        If (Test-Connection $Computer -Count 1){
            $ComputerStatus = manage-bde -status -cn "$Computer" 
            $ComputerStatusCol += $ComputerStatus
        } Else {
            Write-Host("$Computer appears to be offline.")
        }
    }
    $ComputerStatusCol | Out-File -filepath "c:\users\enduser\Bitlocker-Status.txt"
} Else {
    Write-Error "The text file was not found, check the path."
}
```

Comment: Actually, appending to an array in a loop should be avoided, because it tends to perform poorly. The operation doesn't really append to the existing array, instead it creates a new one with increased size, copies all existing values, puts the new item in the free slot at the end, then replaces the old array with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the parameter `-Append` to the `Out-File`, so that your output is appended to the existing content instead of replacing it:

```
$ComputerStatus = manage-bde -status -cn "$Computer" |
    Out-File -filepath "c:\users\enduser\Bitlocker-Status.txt" -append -force
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy batch file for admins who want a nice easy file to look through. Just set this up at one of my clients AD Networks, worked like a charm:
Setup a .cdm file, dump it into the netlogon folder
script:
echo Computer:%ComputerName% with username:%username% - Bitlocker check of drive C: >> "\server\share\folder\BitlockerCheck.log"manage-bde -status c: >> "\server\share\folder\BitlockerCheck\BitlockerCheck.log"

Make sure everyone has access to share path (domain users)Edit Group Policy for the container you want it to run in (default domain policy should never be touched, if you want everyone, make a new policy at the top and name it Bitcloker status check).
Go to User Configuration - Policies - Windows Settings - Scripts Right-click Logon, properties, Add - browse to \dcname\netlogon\filename.cmdclick OK, after about 15 minutes (without a forced gpupdate) the file will start populating as users logon/logoff.

On Non-BitLocker computers, it will show the computer name and user with no info.May be cumbersome on very large networks, but you could break out Gp script by OU and separate files as most large companies don't have everyone in one container.